# What does 'on' mean in chord notation?

Tags: chords, notation

For example, Em(onD) and Em(onC♯). I found these in a Japanese guitar tab book I bought.

Answer (score 9):

As @NReilingh says, it's probably a Japanese alternative to "slash notation".

"C/B" for example -- often read aloud as "C over B" means a C chord played over a prominent B bass note.

The easy way to play these is to have a bassist! You play a normal C, the bassist plays the B.

Without a bassist, you need to sound the bass note yourself. For example, to play G/F# you might use the 2nd fret of the bottom E string, instead of the 3rd fret you'd normally use.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably a shorthand for slash notation. Try putting the "on" note in the bass below whatever other chord is notated.

Comment: You're speaking to me like I have a clue what I'm doing :) I just recently took up playing guitar. Although maybe it would be better to open up a separate question where this slash notation can be described in more detail and link to that from here so it can hopefully be found easier by searching.

Comment: To be fair, you asked the original question like you had a clue what you were doing! The other answers have elaborated fully.

Answer (score 3):

Don't let the term "slash notation" bother you. It's simply a chord that has a bass note(the lowest note) that is not normally part of the chord. You find a lot of these chords in songs by The Beatles for instance.

While you are learning and so new at guitar, I suggest using songbooks that have chord diagrams each time you need to play the chord. In time, you won't need any help remembering the chords.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to slim and NReilingh's answers:

Usually when you see a chord, the lowest note played is the *root* note of the chord.  So when you normally see a chord marked as `Cm` that means play a C minor chord with the lowest note (the bass note) as the *root* -- C: `C, E♭, G`.

Normally you play the chord going up.  So in the `Cm` example, you play the *root* `C`, the *third* `E♭`, and the *fifth* `G`:

[image: Normal Chord]

Musicians like playing around with something called "inversions" of a chord, where you change the ordering of the notes.  Normally first inversion is where the second note (which in our example is the *third* degree of the scale) is played first: `E♭, G, C`.  The C is played higher on the instrument than before:

[image: First inversion]

In the same way, we have second inversion, which is where the *fifth* degree of the scale is played first:

[image: Second inversion]

So what the others were saying follows this logic.  You should probably play an `Em` with the lowest note being a `D` for the `Em(on D)` [`Em/D`].  This can be done in [many ways](http://www.chorderator.com/cgi-bin/generate.py?optionsDisp=no&readableTuning=Guitar%20Standard&chordName=Em/D&tuning=EADGBE&capo=0&size=30)!

For the `Em(onC#)` [`Em/C#`], look [here](http://www.chorderator.com/cgi-bin/generate.py?optionsDisp=no&readableTuning=Guitar+Standard&menuTab=relatedChords&chordName=Em%2FC%23&tuning=EADGBE&capo=0&size=30) for ways to play that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This isn't an inversion. There's no `C♯` or `D` in Em (`E - G - B`).

Comment: @Luke, correct, but understanding inversions can help with understanding the *why* behind slash notation.