# What do the brackets mean?

Tags: piano, chords

I'm trying to learn [Sea Diver](http://www.hunter-mott.com/tablature/sea_diver.html) by Mott the Hoople. The first line of notes are:

`C#(g#) C#(f) F#`

I understand `C#` means play the C major chord one note higher. What does the `(g#)` mean? Does it mean the `g#` should be played as the root of the chord? i.e. with my thumb?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does 'on' mean in chord notation?](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6677/what-does-on-mean-in-chord-notation)

Comment: `C#(f)` should probably be `C#(E#)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is right there on the page you linked to:

> Occasionally chords have another note in a bracket after, these
>   indicate the lowest part of the chord played and probably the bass on
>   the actual recording (sounds better on piano anyway!).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a variation on "slash" notation.

As per your example, `C#(g#)` would normally be written as `C#/G#`.

That would mean to play a C# major chord, but with *G# as the bass note*. This is also called a C# major chord *in second inversion*, or a C# major chord *with the fifth in the bass*.

You see, the notes in a C# major chord are C#, E# and G#, which are the root note, the third note, and the fifth note. If you put the E# as the lowest note, that is a C# major chord *in first inversion*, or a C# major chord *with the third in the bass*. Putting the G# as the lowest note puts it in second inversion.

In the second chord in your example, `C#(f)`, it's less clear, because the note f is not a part of a C# major chord. But the correct way to play it would be to play, in ascending order, F(natural), C#, E# and G#, with the option to leave the C# (the third) out if it sounds too dissonant.

Comment: I believe your answer is correct, though you could say that F _is_ in a C# major chord, because (on a piano) an F sounds just like a C#. So `C#/F` will sound just like `C#/E#` which is the first inversion again.